# Promises in Node.js core

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I hear that Promises are available for Node core APIs.
For example with fs, how can we use promises, do we just omit the callback?

```
fs.readFile(file).then(v => console.log(v));
```

or how do we use?

at the moment for Node.js versions older than 10, I am guessing, it's behind a flag? Maybe: `node --promises`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This experimental feature was added in node v10.0.0. You'll need to require `fs/promises` instead of `fs`

Comment: Are you sure about this?  The [node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) says: `require('fs').promises`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Seems like it was fs/promises not so long ago. Yes, it's `require('fs').promises` now. They wouldn't label it as experimental for nothing.

Comment: I looked into it a bit more and it appears that `fs/promises` is what the latest code shows.  It was changed to that from `fs.promises`.  Not sure if it's been released and certainly not yet in sync with the doc.

Comment: @jfriend00 FYI, just stumbled upon [this comment](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15413#issuecomment-398817793). Current Node `master` uses fs.promises.

Comment: @estus - Yeah, it seems they haven't really made up their mind yet about how it should be done across all the modules.

Answer (score 5):

As of now, most Node callback-based APIs should be manually promisified in order to make use of promises.

`util.promisify` is available since Node 8 (also [polyfillable](https://github.com/ljharb/util.promisify)) and allows to promisify any APIs that use error-first callbacks, including built-in `fs`:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const fs =  require('fs');
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

readFile(file).then(console.log);
```

Some APIs that use non-error-first callbacks support it too via `util.promisify.custom` symbol, e.g. `setTimeout`:

```
promisify(setTimeout)(100).then(...);
```

[`fs.promises` experimental API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) is available since Node 10 ([polyfillable](https://github.com/cravler/fs.promises/) in Node 8 and higher) and contains promisified `fs` module, as already mentioned in another question:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

fsp.readFile(file).then(console.log);
```

For batch promisification third-party tools like [`pify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pify) can be used.

Third-party promisification packages are available for most built-in and popular third-party callback-based packages that can be converted to promises, e.g. [`fs-extra`](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra), which is a preferable drop-in replacement for `fs` that includes essential `graceful-fs` package.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use [mz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mz) :

```
var fs = require('mz/fs');
```

Comment: This isn't the point of the question.  There are lots of ways to "promisfy" the existing fs module or add-on modules to do that.  The question is now to use the built-in promises.

Comment: That is incredibly simple and easy to overlook - thank you