# How to use await in a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code is:

```
async function run() {
  await sleep(1);
  fs.readFile('list.txt', 'utf8', function (err, text) {
    console.log(text);
    await sleep(5);
   });
}

run();
```

`await sleep(1)` is fine, but `await sleep(5)` results in:

> SyntaxError: async is only valid in async function

Is `fs.readFile` the problem? How do I use `await` in such a situation?

The above is a reduced example to test. In my actual usage, I need to put the `await sleep` in a callback deeply nested inside a few more asynchronous functions.

Comment: It is about the third parameter you pass to readFile, which is a function. It has to be async too since you use await inside that function.

Comment: Try adding `async` before function inside `readFile`parameters like this: `fs.readFile('list.txt', 'utf8', async function (err, text) ...`

Comment: The callback function of the `fs.readFile()` is not async function. `await` could be used in only async function.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what `sleep` is doing, but the problem in your question is happening because the callback to `fs.readfile` is not an async function and the that is where `await sleep(5)` is.

```
async function run() {
    await sleep(1);
    fs.readFile('list.txt', 'utf8', function (err, text) {
    console.log(text);           /* ^this isn't an async function */
    await sleep(5);
    });
}
```

You *could* make that error go away by passing an async function as a callback, however mixing promise and callback flows is not recommended and leads to problems, especially when handling errors. It prevents you from chaining the promise and catching errors from the inner await outside of `run()`.

A better approach is to wrap `fs.readFile()` in a promise and await that.

```
async function run() {
  await sleep(1);
  const text = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('list.txt', 'utf8', function (err, text) {
      if (err) reject(err) else resolve(text);
    });
  });
  console.log(text);
  await sleep(5);
}
```

This will allow you to catch any errors in much more robust way with:

```
run()
.then(() => /*...*/)
.catch(err => /* handle error */
```

and avoid unhandled rejections.

Comment: Usually I don't downvote sibling answers, but the accepted answer is just wrong. It may illustrate how it's possible to use `await` in a callback but this should never be done in real life and shouldn't be recommended to no one. That's where UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning and 'why do I have race condition with await run()' kind of questions come from. `await sleep(5)` can't affect anything, for starters.

Comment: @estus, you are correct. Looking at your much more sensible solution, I would delete this if I could, but since it’s selected, I can’t. If you would like to edit it so it’s correct for future users, I wouldn’t mind (I could do that too, but I’d just be blatantly copying you.)

Comment: Sure, feel free to update the answer, I'll retract my vote. It's always better for users to see a usable answer first, and that's how accepted answer is shown to most users.

Answer (score 4):

> The above is a reduced example to test. In my actual usage, I need to put the await sleep in a callback deeply nested inside a few more asynchronous functions.

Callback based APIs shouldn't be augmented with `async..await` or promises in general when there is a chance to stick to promises (may not be possible if a callback is called more than once). This results in poor control flow and error handling.

Once there is `async` callback function inside `run`, it's impossible to chain nested promise with `run().then(...)`. Errors from nested promises may remain unhandled as well and result in `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

The proper way is to move from callbacks to promises and use promise control flow. Generally this can be achieved with promise constructor:

```
async function run() {
  await sleep(1);
  const text = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('list.txt', 'utf8', function (err, text) {
      if (err) reject(err) else resolve(text);
    });
  });
  console.log(text);
  await sleep(5);
}
```

There are [numerous ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51112228/3731501) to get promises from Node callback based APIs, e.g. `fs` provides promise API since Node 10:

```
async function run() {
  await sleep(1);
  const text = await fs.promises.readFile('list.txt', 'utf8');
  console.log(text);
  await sleep(5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your function includes an "await", you **must** prefix your function declaration with "async".

NOTE: By making your function an "async" function a promise is **always** returned. So if you return a string, that string will get automatically wrapped in a Promise object.

You can therefore return a Promise manually (for clarity). A simple resolved promise is sufficient:

```
async function foo(){
    await bar();
    return Promise.resolve('optional'); // optionally resolve with a value
}
```

The keyword "async" always goes before the keyword "function":

```
var foo = async function(){
    await bar();
    return Promise.resolve('optional'); // optionally resolve with a value
}
```

... and well for arrow functions:

```
var foo = sally( async () => {
    await bar();
    return Promise.resolve('optional'); // optionally resolve with a value
})
```

To retrieve the return value:

```
foo().then(val => console.log(val) ); // prints "optional" to console
```

Comment: *"And by making your function an "async" function, you'll need to return a promise. "* `async` functions always wrap the return value in a promise. So your examples are equivalent to `return 'optional';`.

Comment: @felix Thanks for the prompt, the Promise.resolve() returns a Promise object because we're calling the "resolve" method directly off the native window.Promise. It's just a fast, cheap way to create a simple Promise.

Comment: I think Felix's point was that you do NOT need to explicitly return a promise in an `async` function. Not only is it unnecessary but also defeats the purpose of async-await, since the point of an `async` function is that it implicitly returns a promise that wraps whatever you return (or throw) in the function.

Comment: Agreed, but noobs need to be aware that an ```async``` function alters any returned value that is not a promise. Felix implied that the return value was a ```typeof string``` and not a ```typeof promise```.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **aysnc** key before function start. **await** keyword
will not work with normal function.

```
async function run() {
  await sleep(1);
  fs.readFile('list.txt', 'utf8', async function (err, text) {
    console.log(text);
    await sleep(5);
   });
}

run();
```